# Backbone model responsibility

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need some clarification on backbone models and their link with views. My application is standard setup with: backbone on frontend, express/mongo on backend.

Let's say I have these functionalities:

- login
- register
- profile update
- change password
- logout with confirmation

All of these have dedicated api methods on backend and views on frontend. I started with user model (all of functionalities concern user table/api), but found that it's easier to create many models with limited attributes each for one view.

I don't find this approach elegant, as bigger apps can't end with more than 30 models, which would hard to maintain...

Question for pros, how do you divide your functionalities over models?

Comment: I think this article answers some of your questions: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/backbone-js-tips-patterns/

Answer (score 0):

Several approaches could be taken to reuse the functionality but definitely you should try to reuse models and DRY.  The simpler approach would be through prototype augmenting and inheritance of common fields as you can redefine the url to fetch the data from in the children models.

I developed a middle size app with BB and we did it that way but the amount of reusability depends on the domain of your application.

You may consider to take a look of a couple of well designed and mature libraries built on top of BB and at least grab some ideas if none of them suits completely your needs

http://marionettejs.com/

*Backbone.Marionette is a composite application library for Backbone.js that aims to simplify the construction of large scale JavaScript applications.
It is a collection of common design and implementation patterns found in the applications that we have been building with Backbone, and includes pieces inspired by composite application architectures, event-driven architectures, messaging architectures, and more.*

http://chaplinjs.org/

*Chaplin is an architecture for JavaScript applications using the Backbone.js library. Chaplin addresses Backbone’s limitations by providing a lightweight and flexible structure that features well-proven design patterns and best practices.
Chaplin empowers you to quickly develop scalable single-page web applications; allowing you to focus on designing and developing the underlying functionality in your web application.*

Also on Derick Bailey [blog](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey) you will find a lot of great quality posts regarding design aspects for Backbone